# Python folium GeoJSON map not displaying

Tags: pandas, leaflet, geojson, geopandas

I'm trying to use a combination of geopandas, Pandas and Folium to create a polygon map that I can embed  incorporate into a web page.

For some reason, it's not displaying.

The steps I've taken:

1. Grabbed a .shp from the UK's OS for Parliamentary boundaries.
2. I've then used geopandas to change the projection to epsg=4326 and then exported as GeoJSON which takes the following format:

   `{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "PCON13CD": "E14000532", "PCON13CDO": "A03", "PCON13NM": "Altrincham and Sale West" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -2.313999519326579, 53.357408280545918 ], [ -2.313941776174758, 53.358341455420039 ], [ -2.31519699483377, 53.359035664493433 ], [ -2.317953152796459, 53.359102954309151 ], [ -2.319855973429864, 53.358581917200119 ],... ] ] ] } },...`

Then what I'd like to do is mesh this with a dataframe of constituencies in the following format, dty:

```
constituency        count
0   Burton          667
1   Cannock Chase   595
2   Cheltenham      22
3   Cheshire East   2
4   Congleton       1
5   Derbyshire Dales    1
6   East Staffordshire  4

import folium
mapf = folium.Map(width=700, height=370, tiles = "Stamen Toner", zoom_start=8, location=     ["53.0219392","-2.1597434"])


mapf.geo_json(geo_path="geo_json_shape2.json", 
              data_out="data.json", 
              data=dty, 
              columns=["constituency","count"], 
              key_on="feature.properties.PCON13NM.geometry.type.Polygon",
              fill_color='PuRd',
              fill_opacity=0.7, 
              line_opacity=0.2, 
              reset="True")
```

The output from mapf looks like:

mapf.json_data

```
{'../../Crime_data/staffs_data92.json': [{'Burton': 667,
   'Cannock Chase': 595,
   'Cheltenham': 22,
   'Cheshire East': 2,
   'Congleton': 1,
   'Derbyshire Dales': 1,
   'East Staffordshire': 4,
   'Lichfield': 438,
   'Newcastle-under-Lyme': 543,
   'North Warwickshire': 1,
   'Shropshire': 17,
   'South Staffordshire': 358,
   'Stafford': 623,
   'Staffordshire Moorlands': 359,
   'Stoke-on-Trent Central': 1053,
   'Stoke-on-Trent North': 921,
   'Stoke-on-Trent South': 766,
   'Stone': 270,
   'Tamworth': 600,
   'Walsall': 1}]}
```

Although the mapf.create_map() function successfully creates a map, the polygons don't render.

What debugging steps should I take?

Comment: Any chance of posting a live demo of this somewhere for debugging purposes?

Answer (score 1):

@elksie5000, Try mplleaflet it is extremely straightforward.

```
pip install mplleaflet
```

in Jupyter/Ipython notebook:

```
import mplleaflet
ax = geopandas_df.plot(column='variable_to_plot', scheme='QUANTILES', k=9, colormap='YlOrRd')
mplleaflet.show(fig=ax.figure)
```