# folium crashes Jupyter Notebook when using large geojson file

Tags: leaflet, ipython, jupyter-notebook, geojson, folium

I am trying to follow the example of adding a geo_json overlay found [here](http://python-visualization.github.io/folium/quickstart.html#GeoJSON/TopoJSON-Overlays). The geo_json file I am using is this map of the zip codes in Germany, found [here](https://github.com/yetzt/postleitzahlen/blob/master/data/postleitzahlen.geojson). It is large at 85.8 mb.

Here is my MWE; I downloaded the 'postleitzahlen.geojson' file to (pwd being my "present working directory") 'pwd/data/postleitzahlen.geojson'. Note that the same problem happens even when I change the extension from the non-standard .geojson to .json.

```
import folium
# Not sure if I need all of the packages below:
import json
import os

# Center map in middle of Berlin, zoom out enough so all of Germany is visible,
# and use mapbox bright instead of default OpenStreetMap so as to hopefully make
# images easier to render. But it still crashes the notebook anyway.
m=folium.Map(location=[52.5194, 13.4067], tiles='Mapbox Bright', zoom_start=5)

# This is the analog of the example on the Folium website, but I don't really understand it.
# Wouldn't we need to load the file into memory somehow, maybe using geopandas or something?
zipcode_regions = os.path.join('data', 'postleitzahlen.geojson')

# Add the geoJSON layer to map ostensibly:
folium.GeoJson(zipcode_regions, name='geo_json').add_to(m)

# Still crashes regardless of whether I include following line - I think it just adds control in top-right of map on example website, which I don't need.
folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)

m
```

In Jupyter Notebook (on my computer at least) what happens is that for the output of the cell containing the last line, one just gets a large empty white space. Moreover, at the top it says 'Autosave Failed!'. And when one tries to click the save button, the notebook freezes momentarily, and then nothing happens. (I.e. there's no indication that the file was saved.)

I can still run new cells (e.g. performing basic arithmetic), but nothing saves. (EDIT: Nope, doing this too often causes the notebook to crash outright in Chrome.)

This might be a bug in either Jupyter, IPython, or Folium, in which case asking here might not help much. But I figured that I would try asking here at least.

Looking at [the documentation for this function](http://python-visualization.github.io/folium/modules.html) (scroll down a lot), should I try either (1) setting the `overlay` parameter to `True`, since the default is `False`? (2) setting the `smooth_factor` to a float greater than the default of `1.0`? (I will try both and update this post with any results.)

I read these questions, but did not understand how to use their answers to solve my problem. If someone can explain how to apply those answers here, I would greatly appreciate it. [(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42107268/geojson-data-not-displaying-in-python-folium-map)[(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44297213/downloading-geojson-file-into-folium-in-jupyter)[(3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26655531/python-folium-geojson-map-not-displaying)[(4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37003421/folium-choropleth-geojson-raises-attributeerror-nonetype)[(5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45558954/geojson-in-ipython-display-cannot-be-imported-in-jupyter-notebook)

**EDIT:** I tried doing [what this person did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46431442/folium-maps-not-showing-up-on-jupyter-notebook-uploaded-on-github), namely increasing the data limit (specifically I ran `jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1.0e10` to launch Jupyter Notebook) but the same error occurred as before.
**EDIT (2):** Still occurs setting `overlay=True` and both using and not using data limit increase.
**EDIT (3):** Setting `smooth_factor` to `10`, `100`, or `1000` didn't fix it, although it did make the penultimate cell run faster. So this seems more likely a problem with Jupyter than folium.
The terminal output each time for Jupyter Notebook contains multiple errors of the form:

```
Saving file at /map.ipynb
[I 12:00:00.000 NotebookApp] Malformed HTTP message from ::1: Content-Length too long
```

Watching the terminal more closely as the notebook runs, it is clear that this error occurs exactly as the notebook tries to load the map. So next I will try the solutions proposed [here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/650).

**EDIT (4):** Still doesn't work trying the `jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.tornado_settings="{'max_body_size': 104857600, 'max_buffer_size': 104857600}"` suggested [here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/650); also doesn't work when adding three additional zeroes to `max_body_size` and `max_buffer_size`, nor when adding six additional zeroes to both. (I.e. [approx. 0.5 petabytes](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/blob/master/notebook/notebookapp.py#L237-L238), a million times the defaults.)

**EDIT (5):** This is now [posted as an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/issues/787).